# Force readonly when connecting to sqlite file

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbi

On many front ends,
I wish to enforce my scripts using a readonly connection to a sqlite3 file mirrored from a master server.

Is there's a way to say DBI to do this ?

For the moment, I'm doing this:

```
       $dbHand = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$dbName", $dbUser, $dbPass, {
            PrintError => 0,
            RaiseError => 1,
            AutoCommit => 1,
    }) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

And get full access.

- I'm not perl fluent, I have to maintain/evolve existing
- (I don't want to deal with file permissions)

Comment: You can check https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite#dbh-sqlite_set_authorizer-code_ref

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `sqlite_open_flags` attribute as explained in the [DBD::SQLite documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite#Database-Name-Is-A-File-Name):

```
use DBD::SQLite;
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:$dbfile", undef, undef, {
  sqlite_open_flags => DBD::SQLite::OPEN_READONLY,
});
```

This will cause an error if you try to open a database that doesn't exist (normally, a new database would be created) or if you try to write to an existing database.

Note that you have to explicitly `use DBD::SQLite;` in order to use the constant `DBD::SQLite::OPEN_READONLY`.

---

Be aware that DBI provides a [`ReadOnly`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#ReadOnly) handle attribute, but DBD::SQLite doesn't honor it prior to v1.49_05:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dump;
use DBI;

my $db = 'foo.db';
unlink $db if -f $db;

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$db",'','', {
    RaiseError => 1,
    ReadOnly   => 1
});

$dbh->do( q{CREATE TABLE foo(id INTEGER, name TEXT)} );
$dbh->do( q{INSERT INTO foo VALUES(1, 'foo')} );
my $values = $dbh->selectall_arrayref( q{SELECT * FROM foo} );

dd $values;
```

Outputs:

```
[[1, "foo"]]
```

Switching to `sqlite_open_flags => DBD::SQLite::OPEN_READONLY` causes errors.

If the database doesn't exist:

```
DBI connect('dbname=foo.db','',...) failed: unable to open database file
```

If the database exists:

```
DBD::SQLite::db do failed: attempt to write a readonly database
```

---

As of DBD::SQLite v1.49_05, you can also use the `ReadOnly` attribute, but only as an option to `connect`. Setting the attribute after connecting doesn't work and throws a warning:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=$db",'','', {
    RaiseError => 1
});
$dbh->{ReadOnly} = 1;
```

Outputs:

> DBD::SQLite::db STORE warning: ReadOnly is set but it's only advisory

Comment: I noticed that the DBD::SQLite docs made no mention of the `ReadOnly` option and instead showed a completely different way to do it; that made me curious. I opened [a ticket](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=110439) because DBD::SQLite is not keeping its end of the bargain here...it doesn't even warn that `ReadOnly` is ignored!

Answer (score 2):

Just set

```
$dbHand ->{ReadOnly} = 1
```

as described [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#ReadOnly)

Comment: Unfortunately, DBD::SQLite doesn't appear to honor this. See my answer.

Comment: @Overnuts: Please take note of the [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357159/force-readonly-when-connecting-to-sqlite-file/34357263#comment56464231_34357263) and [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34360995/622310) from **ThisSuitIsBlackNot**. It looks like this standard solution is wrong for SQLite

Comment: This has been [fixed in DBD::SQLite 1.49_05](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=110439) (developer release). Unfortunately, you have to set the attribute as an option to `connect`; setting it on the handle after connecting doesn't work and throws a warning.